# How do I properly answer this exercise? I don't know what the answer should look like

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is the exercise asking for multiple lines or 1 line? it keeps telling me its wrong. I don't know why.
I've tried googling but I haven't found anything that makes sense to me. Please help!

```
function exerciseFour(age){
  let typeOfLicense;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called:age
  // You are also given another variable called: typeOfLicense;
  // Using an if/else if/else statement assign typeOfLicense to:
  // 'Full License' if age is greater than or equal to 16,
  // 'Permit' if age is equal to 15,
  // 'None' if age is less than 15
if (age >= 16) {
  typeOfLicense = Full License;
} 
else if (age === 15) {
  typeOfLicense = Permit;
} 
else {
  typeOfLicense = None;
}
```

Comment: You need to quote those strings the same way they did in the comments

Comment: As **Charlietfl** has posted above, you need to wrap your variable value/string with quotes. If you read the  exercise description you will notice each expected string for `typeOfLicense` is wrapped with single quotes. I don't know why this post has been downvoted. The OP has provided detail and an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Just add quotes.

```
function exerciseFour(age){
  let typeOfLicense;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called:age
  // You are also given another variable called: typeOfLicense;
  // Using an if/else if/else statement assign typeOfLicense to:
  // 'Full License' if age is greater than or equal to 16,
  // 'Permit' if age is equal to 15,
  // 'None' if age is less than 15
if (age >= 16) {
  typeOfLicense = 'Full License';
} 
else if (age === 15) {
  typeOfLicense = 'Permit';
} 
else {
  typeOfLicense = 'None';
}
```

Comment: should probably return the variable also

Comment: Possibly though the exercise doesn't say to do that... if it still doesn't work after the change recommended in the answer then yes that'd be the next thing to try.

Comment: I agree the variable must be returned

Answer (score 0):

The actual code issue has been resolved above.

But the thing you need to study and understand is strings in Javascript.

A few mistakes in your code, when you try and use `Permit` without quotation marks, Javascript assumes you are trying to use a variable name, but of course this variable does not exist.

The other mistake in your code, when you try and use `Full License` without quotation marks, Javascript can't workout what the code is and will throw a syntax error, saying `unexpected identifier`. You can't put two variables (identifiers) side by side and this is what Javascript thinks you are trying to do.

This article will be worth studying to fully understand strings:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings